# out of memory error in a viewpager using fragments and imageviews

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I am having this out of memory error I had a viewpager using activity not fragments and imageview then when I got this error I changed it to fragments... but this error keeps showing I tried lots of solutions none of it worked...

my code:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
    private int mPageNumber;
    private int[] pics = {R.drawable.intro1, R.drawable.intro2,R.drawable.intro3,R.drawable.intro4,R.drawable.intro5,R.drawable.intro6,R.drawable.intro7,R.drawable.intro8,
            R.drawable.intro9,R.drawable.intro10,R.drawable.intro11,R.drawable.intro12,R.drawable.intro13,R.drawable.intro14,R.drawable.intro15,R.drawable.intro16,R.drawable.intro17,R.drawable.intro18,
            R.drawable.intro19,R.drawable.intro20,R.drawable.intro21,R.drawable.intro22,R.drawable.intro23,R.drawable.intro24,R.drawable.intro25,R.drawable.intro26,R.drawable.intro27,R.drawable.intro28,R.drawable.intro29,R.drawable.intro30,
            R.drawable.intro31,R.drawable.intro32,R.drawable.intro33,R.drawable.intro34,R.drawable.intro35,R.drawable.intro36,R.drawable.intro37,R.drawable.intro38,R.drawable.intro39,R.drawable.intro40,R.drawable.intro41,R.drawable.intro42,
            R.drawable.intro43,R.drawable.intro44,R.drawable.intro45,R.drawable.intro46,R.drawable.intro47,R.drawable.intro48,R.drawable.intro49,R.drawable.intro50,R.drawable.intro51,R.drawable.intro52,R.drawable.intro53,R.drawable.intro54,
            R.drawable.intro55,R.drawable.intro56,R.drawable.intro57,R.drawable.intro58,R.drawable.intro59,R.drawable.intro60,R.drawable.intro61,R.drawable.intro62,R.drawable.intro63,R.drawable.intro64,R.drawable.intro65,R.drawable.intro66,
            R.drawable.intro67,R.drawable.intro68,R.drawable.intro69,R.drawable.intro70,R.drawable.intro71,R.drawable.intro72,R.drawable.intro73};
    int count=72;//it's the number of the images-1;



    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout, container, false);

        ImageView img=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_pager);
        img.setImageResource(pics[count-mPageNumber]);

        return rootView;
    }


    public int getPageNumber() {
        return mPageNumber;
    }


}
```

then the activity is:

```
public class Introduction_Activity extends FragmentActivity {
     private static final int NUM_PAGES = 73;

    private ViewPager mPager;


    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduction);


        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.imgs_viewpager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(NUM_PAGES-1);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.introduction_, menu);
        return true;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
          ImageView img_view;

        }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);

            }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }




}
```

that's my logcat:

```
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:677)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at packagename.ScreenSlidePageFragment.onCreateView(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:60)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:242)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-01 14:44:49.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4770):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I even added:

```
@Override
    public void onDetach(){
         super.onDetach();
        //img.setImageResource(0);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(this).commit();
        Log.d("was detached","yes");
    }
```

to my fragment and it's still getting me the error;

**EDIT**
I resized my images with a code and recycled the unneeded bitmaps and got this error again:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

    /**
     * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
     */
    ImageView img;
    int height;
    int width;
    private int mPageNumber;
    private int[] pics = {R.drawable.intro1, R.drawable.intro2,R.drawable.intro3,R.drawable.intro4,R.drawable.intro5,R.drawable.intro6,R.drawable.intro7,R.drawable.intro8,
            R.drawable.intro9,R.drawable.intro10,R.drawable.intro11,R.drawable.intro12,R.drawable.intro13,R.drawable.intro14,R.drawable.intro15,R.drawable.intro16,R.drawable.intro17,R.drawable.intro18,
            R.drawable.intro19,R.drawable.intro20,R.drawable.intro21,R.drawable.intro22,R.drawable.intro23,R.drawable.intro24,R.drawable.intro25,R.drawable.intro26,R.drawable.intro27,R.drawable.intro28,R.drawable.intro29,R.drawable.intro30,
            R.drawable.intro31,R.drawable.intro32,R.drawable.intro33,R.drawable.intro34,R.drawable.intro35,R.drawable.intro36,R.drawable.intro37,R.drawable.intro38,R.drawable.intro39,R.drawable.intro40,R.drawable.intro41,R.drawable.intro42,
            R.drawable.intro43,R.drawable.intro44,R.drawable.intro45,R.drawable.intro46,R.drawable.intro47,R.drawable.intro48,R.drawable.intro49,R.drawable.intro50,R.drawable.intro51,R.drawable.intro52,R.drawable.intro53,R.drawable.intro54,
            R.drawable.intro55,R.drawable.intro56,R.drawable.intro57,R.drawable.intro58,R.drawable.intro59,R.drawable.intro60,R.drawable.intro61,R.drawable.intro62,R.drawable.intro63,R.drawable.intro64,R.drawable.intro65,R.drawable.intro66,
            R.drawable.intro67,R.drawable.intro68,R.drawable.intro69,R.drawable.intro70,R.drawable.intro71,R.drawable.intro72,R.drawable.intro73};
    int count=72;//it's the number of the images-1;


    /**
     * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
     */
    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.d("width", ""+width);
        Log.d("height", ""+height);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        Resources res = getResources() ;
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout, container, false);
        Bitmap btm=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(res,pics[count-mPageNumber],600,600);
        img=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_pager);
        img.setImageBitmap(btm);

        return rootView;
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}


    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
        super.onDetach();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        bitmap.recycle();       

        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        //fragmentTransaction.remove(this).commit();

    }


    /**
     * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
     */
    public int getPageNumber() {
        return mPageNumber;
    }


}
```

I can swipe more than before but the problem is still there...
Is there a way to view the free space of the memory of my app? and please does someone have a solution...

Comment: suspicious: getItem() returns a ScreenSlidePageFragment.create() ...?

Comment: 634x700 image in memory gives 1.69 MB not 140KB ... try to use mPager.setCurrentItem(X, false)(not smooth) and set image in ImageView to null after ScreenSlidePageFragment instance  is detached from activity

Comment: @MiStr yes so it creates a new fragment and adds the layout containing the image in it..

Comment: Try looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188767/how-to-get-position-of-arraylist-in-own-adapter)

Comment: @Selvin how can I set the image to null when the fragment is detached from activity?

Comment: first google: Fragment lifecycle, next in overrided onXxxxxxxx of your fragment use `setImageDrawable(null);` on ImageView

Comment: @Selvin I used your method still having the error I even removed the fragment once its detached and still having same propblem

Comment: @User try to resize your images and use a cache...

Comment: @JaAd already tried to do that and had problems but will do it again maybe it will work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add:

android:largeHeap="true"

to my app manifest!!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you don't display bitmap efficiently (btw, remember that logcat is not an optional, you have always to post it).

I suggest you to read and implement by yourself [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only image in your apl, try this code

```
public class Animals extends Activity{
    private static final String POS = "PosAnimals";
    private static ViewPager viewPager;
    private SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
    private Context context;

    boolean flag;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        AnotherAnotherOneAdapter pagerAdapter = new AnotherAnotherOneAdapter();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);  

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
        params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.screenBrightness = -1f;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);


    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(mySharedPreferences.getInt(POS, 0));
    }

    public void onPause(){
        context = getApplicationContext();
        mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(POS, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        editor.commit();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public class AnotherAnotherOneAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private int[] mImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.anim1,
                R.drawable.anim2,
                R.drawable.anim3,
                R.drawable.anim4,
                R.drawable.anim5,
                R.drawable.anim6,
                R.drawable.anim7,
                R.drawable.anim8,
                R.drawable.anim9,
                R.drawable.anim10,
                R.drawable.anim11,
                R.drawable.anim12,
                R.drawable.anim13,
                R.drawable.anim14
        };

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
            Context context = Animals.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ImageView) view);
        }

        public int getCount(){
            return mImages.length;
        }

        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        public void finishUpdate(View arg0){
        }

        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
        }

        public Parcelable saveState(){
            return null;
        }

        public void startUpdate(View arg0){
        }
    }
}
```

and layout of this activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I recommend using the image height is not more than 750 pixels